# C++: Where to get frame rate limiter that doesn't use v-sync?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, frame-rate

This seems like a huge secret among programmers, nobody wants to share their codes for this. Why?

I can't find a working FPS limiter that could limit FPS at least to 60 without using v-sync.

And I want, of course, do it the right way. So i haven't made own yet, because they all say it took them a year to learn all the tricks in fps limiters...

**Edit:** here is my fps limiter code which isnt perfect, but its best i could do, it still tears though:

```
timeBeginPeriod(1);

frame_start_time = TimerGetTime();

while(!done){
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT){
            done = 1;
        }else{
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }else if(active){ 
        draw_everything();
        SwapBuffers(hDC);

        // fps limiter:
        one_frame_limit = 1000.0f/(float)framerate_limit; // 16.666 ms
        while((time_left = one_frame_limit-(TimerGetTime()-frame_start_time)) > 0){
            if(time_left >= 6.0f){
                Sleep((int)(time_left/6.0f));
            }else{
                Sleep(0); // sleep less than 1ms
            }
        }
        frame_start_time = TimerGetTime();
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:** heres my second try, using waitable timers as suggested:

```
float one_frame_limit = 1000.0f/(float)framerate_limit;
float time_left = one_frame_limit-(TimerGetTime()-frame_start_time); // 4.7432ms
liDueTime.QuadPart = -(LONGLONG)(time_left*10000.0f);
if(SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0)){
    WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE);
}
while((time_left = one_frame_limit-(TimerGetTime()-frame_start_time)) > 0.003f){
    Sleep(0);
}
frame_start_time = TimerGetTime();
```

Works better i think. But still tearing... Notice that i added the while loop there because it was tearing more than without it.

--

**Another question:** is this initialization safe?:

```
HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;
liDueTime.QuadPart = -100000LL; // testing timer: wait for 10ms

hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
if(hTimer == NULL){
    waitable_timer_supported = 0;
}else if(!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0)){
    waitable_timer_supported = 0;
}else if(WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0){
    waitable_timer_supported = 0;
}
```

I am afraid the last 2 checks could fail even if the waitable timer is supported... so far it hasnt failed. Is this the right approach of checking for its support?

Comment: I don't understand. To limit the framerate you can either continue to do other work until enough time has passed to render another frame, or you can just sleep and do nothing. What's the problem?

Comment: VSync is a very nice way to do it though as you can be sure it will automatically pick a sensible rate, even on "odd" hardware. Rendering at exactly 60Hz on a 70Hz display will probably see a lot of tearing.

Comment: v-sync doesnt work on my laptop, and not even nearly on every gfx card, and v-sync makes cpu usage huge and lags a lot when i switch my window. with my crappy fps limiter it doesnt lag at all and cpu usage is 0-1%

Comment: So you already implemented a limiter? What is the problem with it?

Comment: the problem is its not perfect, its tearing... and i dont really understand why, i will post the code here soon.

Comment: pasted my code now, see if you can see a problem in it

Comment: Vertical sync is the very thing that solves _tearing_. You can not get rid of tearing _without_ using vsync. Tearing is caused by switching the frame buffer while the screen is still drawing the picture, which results in one half of the screen showing the previous frame (the seam is the tear). Vsync is the moment the screen gets ready to draw from the top again - Giving you the ability to switch frame buffers without tearing.

Comment: is it possible to avoid v-sync from using 100% of my cpu then? my FPS limiter uses only 3-7% cpu now, and i would like it to be that way.

Comment: @Newbie: All versions of Windows (unless you want to go back to like, 95 or something) support waitable timers. You don't need to worry that you could be on a system that won't support them.

Comment: what if someone runs this program under wine?

Answer (score 2):

Set a system timer to go off every 16.6666ms and do your rendering on that event. Better yet, do your rendering and page flip on the timer and start rendering the next frame. This is not a big secret, you can do it in windows using the high-resolution timers.

Once you get this working, you'll see tearing and decide to wait for v-sync instead of some arbitrary timer.

Comment: atm my gfx card v-sync is flawed, it tears too. and the most important reason to get non-v-sync fps limiter is to reduce cpu usage so when i switch window for a second, my whole computer doesnt lag.

Comment: You are doing a page-flip immediately on v-sync right? Then you render the next frame after and don't flip unless it's a complete frame. Just checking...

Comment: what do you mean by complete frame? that i wait until the frame has reached 16.66ms?

Comment: I mean that you've completed rendering it. Then you must wait for the next v-sync to page flip. You are free to start rendering the next frame to another buffer while waiting. You must flip to a completed frame on v-sync or tearing will happen.

Comment: @phkahler: can you provide sample code to show how this process would work differently from my current code example ?

Answer (score 1):

In DirectX, you can simply pass an argument to Present() that will idle the current thread until it returns that will cap the FPS at some multiple of the refresh rate. I've used it and can say that my system achieved about 1% CPU use by using this system. Your current code is wrong basically because Sleep is the least reliable function, ever, in short, and you should virtually never use it with a non-zero argument.

You could try using QueryPerformanceCounter along with Sleep().

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq, begin, end;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&begin);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
const unsigned __int64 waitinticks = static_cast<unsigned __int64>(static_cast<double>(1000)/60));
while(end.QuadPart - begin.QuadPart < waitinticks) {
    Sleep(0); // If someone else wants to run, let them.
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
}
```

The best thing to do is still to use a waitable timer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492(v=VS.85).aspx. This will sleep your thread until the timer alerts it.

Comment: sorry, im using opengl, forgot to add into tags. I tried with Sleep(0) before but it made 100% cpu usage or near 100%...

Comment: @Newbie: Try using the waitable timer.

Comment: i tried your code but it doesnt seem to do anything, my fps doesnt seem to get limited at all.

Comment: not to mention, there was a syntax error in your code, not sure if i fixed it correct but i removed the last ) mark at "1000)/60));" to make it compile.

Comment: Could you also explain how this waitable timer value is set? i dont seem to get a grasp of "-100000000LL" how to set for example 16.66666ms there? Edit: i managed to do "-10000000LL/60LL;" but it gives sometimes 17ms etc instead of 16.666, not very precise? or am i doing something wrong? Edit: i got few times exactly 16.66ms ! but as i said before, its not always the same... might wait too much. well, i try using this anyways

Comment: woohoo, got it working with waitable timer, but the tearing is much more intensive than with my original code. im trying to reduce tearing now somehow if i can...

Comment: added the waitable timer code on my question message. see if theres something to fix?

Comment: crap. if the "liDueTime.QuadPart" gets too high, i get low FPS, about 33fps, any ideas? the old FPS limiter didnt have this problem :/

Comment: eg. if my FPS is getting too high, i get low FPS due to trying to slow down the program with this waitable timer.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me if there is some magic that makes me wrong, but as far as I understand, VSync and tearing go hand-in-hand.  No matter what your frame limit is, you will still get tearing if the frame buffer gets flipped in the middle of a frame.  This is what VSync is for.

As for frame limiting code, here are some techniques for doing producer/consumer time stepping:

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

His reasons seem to focus on physics, but it is perfectly applicable to frame limiting, as well.

Comment: unfortunately my gfx card v-sync tears too, but at least it always tears at the same place (about 100pixels from top)

Comment: @Newbie: This doesn't sound right.  If you have an nVidia video card, you can force all 3D applications to use VSync (maybe w/ others as well, though I've never had a non-nVidia card that I bothered w/ 3D settings).  Have you tried this?  Also, what is the framerate you are getting, and are you using double buffering?

Comment: i have ATI card, my nvidia card indeed supported v-sync by default on all apps. and it was really good, no tearing nor high CPU usage. ATI just sucks i guess. but the nvidia card was about 10 times faster as well... my screen refresh rate is 60 and i get 60fps, and i am using double buffering.

Comment: @Newbie: Stupid suggestion, but you should make sure you install the latest ATI drivers.  I saw on google somewhere that updating drivers fixed a similar problem for one person.  Maybe you'll get lucky...

Comment: i doubt this will fix my laptop too, since v-sync is totally not working with it.